# PHP-jQuery Displaying items properly

Tags: php, jquery

I have a problem. I want to display every "subject" (titles) in the page and not only the first one like now. When I add a new message, index only displays the first one, and only when I click on the "open" button I can see all the messages.

Any suggestion?

Many thanks.

This is de code:

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");
if (isset($_SESSION['username']) === FALSE){
    header('location:login.php');
    exit();
}
$where = "";
$searchCriteria = "";
if (isset($_GET['search']) && $_GET['search'] != '') {
    $searchCriteria = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);
    $where = " WHERE subject LIKE '%" . $searchCriteria . "%'";
    $where .= " OR message like '%" . $searchCriteria . "%'";
}
$sql = "SELECT * FROM notes " . $where . " LIMIT 30";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a><br/><br/>

<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="add-message">
        <a href="add.php"><img src="images/add.png" title="Add"> Add a New   Message</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <?php
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    ?>
    <?php echo $row['subject']; ?>
    <input type="button" id="opener" value="Open"/>
        <div id="playbox"> 
            <table id="general">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="general-header"></th>
                        <th class="general-subject">Subject</th>
                        <th class="general-message">Message</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" class="general-foot"><input type="button" id="closer" value="Close"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><img src="images/edit.png" title="Edit"> Edit</a>
                                                     &nbsp;|&nbsp; 
                            <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><img src="images/delete.png" title="Delete"> Delete</a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="subject"><?php echo $row['subject']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php if ($row['filename']!=''){?>
                            <img align="right" width="300px" src="<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>" />
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php echo $row['message']; ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
            </table>
        </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#playbox").hide();

    $("#opener").click(function(){
        $("#playbox").slideDown(600); 
    });

    $("#closer").click(function(){
        $("#playbox").slideUp(600); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `mysql_num_rows` for that and you don't have need that you create many `open` and `close` `buttons` in `while loop`, just add this once like if you `records then`, for that you have to add `if condition` like `if(mysql-num_rows($result))`

**Full Code**

```
<?php
    require_once("config.php");
    if (isset($_SESSION['username']) or $_SESSION['username']=== FALSE){
        header('location:login.php');
        exit();
    }
    $where = "";
    $searchCriteria = "";
    if (isset($_GET['search']) && $_GET['search'] != '') {
        $searchCriteria = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);
        $where = " WHERE subject LIKE '%" . $searchCriteria . "%'";
        $where .= " OR message like '%" . $searchCriteria . "%'";
    }
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM notes " . $where . " LIMIT 30";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a><br/><br/>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="add-message">
        <a href="add.php"><img src="images/add.png" title="Add"> Add a New   Message</a>
    </div>
    <br>
    <?php
    if(mysql_num_rows($result))
    {
        ?>
        <input type="button" id="opener" value="Open"/>
        <div id="playbox"> 
            <table id="general">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="general-header"></th>
                        <th class="general-subject">Subject</th>
                        <th class="general-message">Message</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="4" class="general-foot"><input type="button" id="closer" value="Close"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </tfoot>
                <?php
                while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                ?>
                <?php echo $row['subject']; ?>

                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <a href="edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><img src="images/edit.png" title="Edit"> Edit</a>
                                                     &nbsp;|&nbsp; 
                            <a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']; ?>"><img src="images/delete.png" title="Delete"> Delete</a>
                        </td>
                        <td class="subject"><?php echo $row['subject']; ?></td>
                        <td><?php if ($row['filename']!=''){?>
                            <img align="right" width="300px" src="<?php echo $row['filename']; ?>" />
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php echo $row['message']; ?>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
                <?php
                }

            ?>
            </table>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#playbox").hide();
    $("#opener").click(function(){
        $("#playbox").slideDown(600); 
    });
    $("#closer").click(function(){
        $("#playbox").slideUp(600); 
    });
});
</script>
```

If you want to `toggle` it separately then you have to code like,

**HTML**

Let there are two records `Create` the `HTML` like using `while loop`

```
<div class="contentSubject">
    <input type="button" class="btnOpener" value="Open" />
    <div class="playbox">
        <!--your table goes here-->
    </div>
</div>

<div class="contentSubject">
    <input type="button" class="btnOpener" value="Open" />
    <div class="playbox">
        //your table goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".playbox").hide();
        $(".btnOpener").click(function(){
            $(this).closest('.contentSubject')
                   .find(".playbox").slideDown(600); 
        });
        // same code for close
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Now I have only one "open" and "close" buttons for all the subjects. But, would it be possible to have an "open" and "close" buttons for each subject displayed. I know your way is more simple and reasonable, but I need this other option too. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi,

With the code above I can display and hide "all" the posts at the same time, but what I want is to open and hide separated. That is, each post with its respective open and hide buttons. I need to display the posts individually in a list. Thanks.

Comment: @user2421425 test the above answer I've changed it.

Answer (score 0):

please try that code

```
$("#opener").live("click",function(){
    $("#playbox").slideDown(600); 
});
```